# Java clipboard as stack in paste override

Tags: java, stack, customization, clipboard

I have done my research, no useful results found.

Here is the deal, I'm writing a 'new' clipboard that works like a stack instead of a 'area'. And I'm brave or stupid enoght to do that in Java. So far in my tests to see if this is possible I have managed to create this stack behavior. The only problem I'm getting is that sometimes, mainly when I paste the top of the stack (pop operation), it doesn't pop or for some other reason it pastes twice.

Example:
If i copy this three words: Carlos, Lucas, Eastwood
The stack clipboard behaves like this at paste: Eastwood, Eastwood, Lucas, Carlos

I'm using JNativeHooks for reading the system keypresses and determining when the user is pasting.
I think what is happening is that the system is pasting before my code... Well, here is the code anyway (It is a test, that explains why it is badly commented):

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.util.Stack;

import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import org.jnativehook.NativeHookException;
import org.jnativehook.NativeInputEvent;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyEvent;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyListener;

public class Test3 implements NativeKeyListener {

Clipboard sysClip = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
Stack<Transferable> clipStack = new Stack<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
    } catch (NativeHookException ex) {
        System.err
                .println("There was a problem registering the native hook.");
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());

        System.exit(1);
    }
    Test2 t2 = new Test2();
    // Construct the example object and initialze native hook.
    GlobalScreen.getInstance().addNativeKeyListener(t2);
}

@Override
public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent ev) {
    // Copy
    if (ev.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VK_C
            && NativeInputEvent.getModifiersText(ev.getModifiers()).equals(
                    "Ctrl")) {
        // Clip the pop
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        clipStack.push(sysClip.getContents(null));

        System.out.println("Ctrl+C : Stack(" + clipStack.size() + ")");
    }
    // Paste
    if (ev.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VK_V
            && NativeInputEvent.getModifiersText(ev.getModifiers()).equals(
                    "Ctrl")) {
        // Clip the pop
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (clipStack.size() > 1) {
            sysClip.setContents(clipStack.pop(), null);
        } else
            sysClip.setContents(clipStack.peek(), null);

        System.out.println("Ctrl+V : Stack(" + clipStack.size() + ")");
    }
}

@Override
public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent e) {

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think the same as you suggested.

Have a copy and paste key combination something different from `ctrl+c` and `ctrl+v` and you can even bypass using the system clipboard. Simply push the selected text and pop the text directly to your text pointer in your application provided of course that you are using this stack behavior for only a particular application.

The system retains it's own copy of latest clip and it gets a duplicate from your `sysClip.setContents(clipStack.pop(), null)` on paste operation.

I don't have much idea on disabling the system behavior. You can do research on that. But you can always make sure that it's the only problem by changing the key combination.

Comment: Thanks! I solved that, there is a topic explaning how I did it at [link](http://www.thejavahub.net/thejavahub/index.php?topic=2601.0).

Comment: Hey, I saw your solution. Glad that you found the solution. However, I was wondering if I could get your source code if you don't mind. I just want to refer it. For enhancing knowledge you know...!!

Comment: I'll post to github soon enough.